# Read numbers from text file to 2D array

Tags: c

Despite the numerous examples on here I can't seem to get this working...

I have a text file, containing many rows, each row has three (int) values separated by a single space. For example:

```
1 0 0
0 0 0
1 0 1
0 0 2
1 0 2
```

I am trying to read this into a 2d array.

My code so far:

```
    int main(void)
    {
       char c;
       int i = 0;
       int maxLines = 18;
       char lines[maxLines][BUFSIZ];
       FILE *fp = fopen("inputs/control.txt", "r");

       if (fp == 0)
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "failed to open inputs/control.txt\n");
           exit(1);
       }

       char buffer[maxLines];
       while (i < maxLines && fgets(buffer[i], sizeof(buffer[0]), fp))
       {
          sscanf (buffer, "%d %d %d", &lines[i][0], &lines[i][1], &lines[i][2]);    
          i++;
       }

       fclose(fp);
       return 0;
    }
```

Can someone provide advice how I can develop this further so that each value in the row is stored in a separate array index?  In my example above, we would store something like:

```
lines[0][0] = 1
lines[0][1] = 0
lines[0][2] = 0
and so on.....
```

Currently it stores the entire row in a single array pos.

As you can probably tell I'm a C noob, any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Your issue is one of parsing numbers from the line. Let it read the whole line into a `buffer`, and then use `sscanf` to read each value into your array, then move to the next line. `sscanf (buffer, "%d %d %d", &lines[i][0], &lines[i][1], &lines[i][2]);`

Comment: Note that `lines[i][strlen(lines[i])] = '\0'` overwrites the `'\0'` with the same value.

Comment: `str[strlen(str)] = '\0'` no effect. E.g str[] = { a, b, c, 0}, str[3] == '\0'

Comment: It is an assumption that ignores the flow of the talking.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks!  Could you possibly elaborate on your buffer . sscanf technique.  I will post a reply below with my code.  EDIT - updated original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were well on your way, you just had problems thinking you were reading a character array instead of an array of signed characters (which could be changed to int, etc) Here is your example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXB 32
#define MAXL 18
#define MAXD 3

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int numlines = 0;
    char buf[MAXB] = {0};
    char lines[MAXL][MAXD];

    FILE *fp = fopen("inputs/control.txt", "r");

    if (fp == 0)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "failed to open inputs/control.txt\n");
       return 1;
    }

    while (i < MAXL && fgets (buf, MAXB - 1, fp))
    {
        if (sscanf (buf, "%hhd %hhd %hhd", &lines[i][0], &lines[i][1], &lines[i][2]) == 3)
            i++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    numlines = i;
    int j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < numlines; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < MAXD; j++)
            printf (" line[%2d][%2d] : %hhd\n", i, j, lines[i][j]);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/read_array_a3
 line[ 0][ 0] : 1
 line[ 0][ 1] : 0
 line[ 0][ 2] : 0
 line[ 1][ 0] : 0
 line[ 1][ 1] : 0
 line[ 1][ 2] : 0
 line[ 2][ 0] : 1
 line[ 2][ 1] : 0
 line[ 2][ 2] : 1
 line[ 3][ 0] : 0
 line[ 3][ 1] : 0
 line[ 3][ 2] : 2
 line[ 4][ 0] : 1
 line[ 4][ 1] : 0
 line[ 4][ 2] : 2
```

**Note:** `char lines[MAXL][MAXD];` is fine, you just must understand that each element is restricted to an **8-bit** signed value, meaning values between `-128 < val < 127`. You can make them `int` if you need to store larger values.

Comment: Brilliant!!  Thanks so much David.  I've learn't something tonight... :)

Comment: Glad I could help. There are 10 different ways to do it, using `sscanf` or just using a pointer, but this is fairly standard. C is a brilliant language, but like anything worth learning, it takes a bit of time.

Answer (score 3):

Use `scanf`. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, j;
    int lines[18][3];
    i = 0;
    while (
        i != sizeof(lines) / sizeof(lines[0])
     && 3 == scanf("%i %i %i", lines[i] + 0, lines[i] + 1, lines[i] + 2)
    ) {
        i++;
    }
    for (j = 0; j !=i; j++) {
        printf("%i %i %i\n", lines[j][0], lines[j][1], lines[j][2]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the input is read from stdin (use `fscanf` for more flexibility), meaning that the snippet above must be called as `./a.out < data.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Using fgets you are reading the whole line from the file. You will need to then parse this line to extract individual numbers and store them into the array. In the while loop you can read the line in a buffer and then use something like strtok/sscanf to parse each number.

Comment: `strtok()` is not really useful here, use `strtol()` or `sscanf()`.  `sscanf()` is a little easier.