# Reading into 2D array from file in C

Tags: c

I'm working on a custom size Tic Tac Toe game.
I would like to make a save file, so if the user leave the game before it ends, he can load the previous game again to continue.

I used enum for one cell and also a struct.

```
typedef enum Cell {                                    
   c_empty, c_circle, c_cross
} Cell;

typedef struct Game {
    Cell** board;
    int SIZE;
} Game;


Game gboard;
static void file_write(Game* pgboard);
static void file_read(Game* pgboard);
```

---

Reading the SIZE already works with this:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", &pgboard->SIZE);
```

And writing it into file too:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", pgboard->SIZE);
```

Also writing the board into the file works with switch:

```
for (j = 0; j < pgboard->SIZE; ++j){
    for (i = 0; i < pgboard->SIZE; ++i){
        switch (pgboard->board[j][i]) {
            case c_empty:   fprintf(fp, " "); break;
            case c_circle:  fprintf(fp, "o"); break;
            case c_cross:   fprintf(fp, "x"); break;
        }
```

So my file is something like this now:

```
  13
  x          o                                                    x
```

Do you have any tips how can I read back the board?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read numbers from text file to 2D array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064121/read-numbers-from-text-file-to-2d-array)

Comment: try to read line by line from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the better way would be to read/write your data in number format instead of string, anyway here is a code that do what you want.

```
char cell;

fscanf(fp, "%d", &pgboard->SIZE);
fscanf(fp, "%c", &cell); /* to get rid of new line */

for (j = 0; j < pgboard->SIZE; ++j){
    for (i = 0; i < pgboard->SIZE; ++i){
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &cell)
        switch (cell) {
            case ' ': pgboard->board[j][i] = c_empty; break;
            case 'o': pgboard->board[j][i] = c_circle; break;
            case 'x': pgboard->board[j][i] = c_cross; break;
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't test the code but it will show the gist of the idea.

Comment: Yes I see the idea. Well the program crash when it goes to the case (with Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.)

Comment: @GregX OK, I edit the code, I forgot file handle for fscanf,

Comment: yes I already edited that in my code but it still crash for some reason. When cell is for example 'x', it goes to the case and then I get that error.

Comment: my code is very similar to your code, I don't know what is the problem, I just guess there is something wrong with pgboard->board. you might miss some allocation.

Comment: Oh, I'm blind! Indeed the allocation was behind the call, silly me.
Thank you for the help it works now just as I wanted to!