# How to read a .txt file in C and store the numbers into a 2D array

Tags: c

So I have the following Matrix in a .txt file given to me by my professor:

```
3.000000,1.000000,1180.000000,1955.000000,221900.000000
3.000000,2.250000,2570.000000,1951.000000,538000.000000
2.000000,1.000000,770.000000,1933.000000,180000.000000
4.000000,3.000000,1960.000000,1965.000000,604000.000000
3.000000,2.000000,1680.000000,1987.000000,510000.000000
4.000000,4.500000,5420.000000,2001.000000,1230000.000000
3.000000,2.250000,1715.000000,1995.000000,257500.000000
3.000000,1.500000,1060.000000,1963.000000,291850.000000
3.000000,1.000000,1780.000000,1960.000000,229500.000000
3.000000,2.500000,1890.000000,2003.000000,323000.000000
```

and I'm suppose to be able to store the first 4 elements in each row into a 2D array. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do it for a 2D array. Any suggestions?

Edit:
Here is what I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
FILE *train; 
FILE *test; 
int row,cols;
int num = 0; 
char single [150]; 
char single1 [150]; 
train = fopen(argv[1],"r");
test = fopen(argv[2],"r");
if(argc < 3){
    printf("error\n");
    return 0; 
}
char *a = fgets(single,150,train);
int attributes = atoi(a); 
char *b = fgets(single,150,train); 
int examples = atoi(b); 
printf("%d\n%d\n\n",attributes,examples);
int matX[attributes][examples]; 

for(row = 0; row < attributes;row++){
    for(cols = 0; cols < examples;cols++){
        matX[row][cols] = atoi(fgets(single,150,train)); 
    }
}
printArray(row,cols,matX);
```

attributes is the number of elements i have to store from each row, and examples is the number of rows in the Matrix. Is this method even viable?

Comment: Can you at least show us how you think a 2D array is declared?  What part of the problem are you having trouble with?

Comment: Answered many, many times, e.g. [Reading matrix from txt file in C Language and store it in allocated 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/qustions/30064121/read-numbers-from-text-file-to-2d-array?rq=1), [Read numbers from text file to 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064121/read-numbers-from-text-file-to-2d-array?rq=1), etc. (just look at the Right side of your browser window under **Related**)

Answer (score 0):

you could try `sscanf`

```
char line ="3.000000,1.000000,1180.000000,1955.000000,221900.000000";
float v0, v1, v2, v3;
sscanf(line, "%f,%f,%f,%f", &v0, &v1, &v2, &v3);
```

Comment: Read the file line by line onto a buffer, and consider the given example. Then set the 2d array values to v0, etc

Comment: Interesting: 5 values and 4 `float`.

Comment: Thanks, but with sscanf I think I have to know how many variables i'm working with. For this assignment I have to scan the file as if i dont know how many I'm working with. I was looking into fscanf and am a lot closer to figuring it out.